# SQL - nested joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design

I have a mySQL database in which I'm trying to output a list of users and their assigned, administrative roles. My tables look something like:

```
Users:
-------
- id
- fname
- lname


Role_Names
-----------
- rn_id
- role_name


Roles
---------
- role_id
- user_id
```

here's some data:

```
Users:
-------
1  'Chris'  'Christy'
2  'Brian'  'Bobson'
3  'Jen'    'Sanders'

Role_Names
--------------
1  'admin'
2  'exec'
3  'employee'

Roles
-----------
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   3
3   3
3   2
```

and for my query, I'm using:

```
SELECT Users.fname, Role_Names.role_name from Users INNER JOIN 
    Roles on Users.id = Roles.user_id
        INNER JOIN Role_Names
            ON Roles.rn_id = Roles.role_id;
```

It only seems to be outputting roles for the 1st `user_id` in the `Roles` table. And it's outputting more than 1 of the same record. For example, my output looks like:

```
first_name      role_name
--------------------------------------
Chris           exec
Chris           exec
Chris           exec
Chris           employee
Chris           employee
Chris           employee
Chris           admin
Chris           admin
Chris           admin
```

whereas I was hoping for something more like:

```
first_name      role_name
--------------------------------------
Chris           employee
Chris           admin
Chris           exec
Brian           employee
Jen             employee
Jen             exec
...
```

At tis point I'm not sure if it's my table structure that is flawed or if I'm using joins incorrectly or if it's that plus a bunch of other stuff I don't even know about. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `distinct`

```
with Users as
(
select 1 id, 'Chris' fname,  'Christy' lname
union all
select 2 , 'Brian',  'Bobson' union all
select 3  ,'Jen'  ,  'Sanders'
),Role_Names as
(
select 1 rn_id,  'admin' role_name
union all
select 2 , 'exec' union all
select 3 , 'employee'
) , Roles as
(
select 1 role_id,1 user_id
    union all
     select 1,2 union all
     select 1,3 union all
     select 2  , 3 union all
select 3  , 3 union all
select 3 ,  2
) SELECT distinct Users.fname, Role_Names.role_name 
  from Users left JOIN 
    Roles on Users.id = Roles.user_id
        left JOIN Role_Names
            ON Role_Names.rn_id = Roles.role_id
```

you missed join in your query

```
JOIN Role_Names ON Roles.rn_id = Roles.role_id -- here both side you use Roles
```

Comment: so that query resulted in 3 records for the same user (1 for each role he holds). The rest of the users are not returned

Comment: @Daveh0 use left join

Comment: @ Zaynul Abadin Tuhin - that gets closer - now the other users' name are being returned but it's showing `NULL` for their `role_name`. The 1st user is being displayed correctly.

Comment: @Daveh0 share the sample data set and it output otherwise how it generate null really tough to understand

Comment: I've added sample data to the OP and here is the output with your query: `[ {first_name: 'Chris', role_name: 'employee'}, {first_name: 'Chris', role_name: 'admin'}, {first_name: 'Chris', role_name: 'exec'}, {first_name: 'Bran', role_name: 'employee'}, {first_name: 'Brian', role_name: NULL}, {first_name: 'Jen', role_name: NULL} ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188040/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-daveh0).

Comment: Isn't that a bit overly complex?

Answer (score 2):

Stare at this piece of your query:  `ON Roles.rn_id = Roles.role_id;`

It is not what you meant!

Here is the fixed query (with clearer formatting):

```
SELECT  Users.fname, Role_Names.role_name
    FROM        Users AS u
    INNER JOIN  Roles AS r        ON u.id = r.user_id
    INNER JOIN  Role_Names AS rn  ON rn.rn_id = r.role_id
```

Tip:  Many:many mapping tables (your `Roles`) are typically named by the the two things it relates.  So I suggest `User_Roles`.  Then the 3rd table can be simply `Roles`.  That leads to

```
SELECT  Users.fname, Role_Names.role_name
    FROM        Users AS u
    INNER JOIN  User_Roles AS ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
    INNER JOIN  Roles      AS r  ON r.rn_id = ur.role_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT` like following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.fname, Role_Names.role_name from Users INNER JOIN 
    Roles on Users.id = Roles.user_id
        INNER JOIN Role_Names
            ON Roles.rn_id = Roles.role_id;
```

Comment: so that query resulted in 3 records for the same user (1 for each role he holds). The rest of the users are not returned

Comment: Ideally you should not be using DISTINCT until you have duplicate mapping.

Comment: Can you share some sample data, as your query looks perfectly fine. Until you have not defined any row limit.

Comment: data added to OP

Comment: Your sample data should give you the correct output. Did you tested your query with the sample data.

Comment: You missed the bug in the last `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query.

```
SELECT Users.fname, Role_Names.role_name 
from Roles RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    Users on Users.id = Roles.user_id
        INNER JOIN Role_Names
            ON Roles_Names.rn_id = Roles.role_id;
```

Comment: so that query resulted in 3 records for the same user (1 for each role he holds). The rest of the users are not returned

Comment: now it is showing results for only 1 user:  `[ {first_name: 'Chris', role_name: 'employee'}, {first_name: 'Chris', role_name: 'admin'}, {first_name: 'Chris', role_name: 'exec'} ]`,

Comment: You missed the bug in the last `ON` clause.